# Access Page resource element

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

How can I access page resource element in C# coding? I have the following piece of code in my XAML. I want to access the `image` element in my C# Code, but it is not accessible.

```xml
<Page.Resources>
 <DataTemplate x:Key="Standard250x250ItemTemplate">
     <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="150" Height="150">
         <Border Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}">
             <Image x:Name="image" Source="{Binding Image}"  Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}" />
         </Border>    
     </Grid>
 </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not accessible because a DataTemplate resource does not get instantiated until it is loaded. You would need to do something like this to load it first:

```
var dataTemplate = (DataTemplate)this.Resources["Standard250x250ItemTemplate"];
var grid = dataTemplate.LoadContent();
```

and then traverse the element tree to get to the Image.

A better approach in many scenarios is to define an attached dependency property or attached behavior that you can attach to your Image in XAML and write code related to the associated Image.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on when you are trying to access it. If trying to access the image control of elements that have already been rendered then you can use ItemContainerGenerator like such:

```
    //assumes using a ListView
    var item = (ListViewItem)listView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(myModel);

    // traverse children
    var image = GetChildOfType<Image>(item);
    // use the image!

private T GetChildOfType<T>(DependencyObject obj)
{
    for(int i = 0; i< VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
        if(child is T) return child as T;

        T item = GetChildOfType<T>(child);
        if(item != null) return item;
    }
    return null;
}
```

If you need to change properties of the image, then that can be accomplished through binding as well.